# Why will a batch file fail when run from a C# app, but not when run on it's own?

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application

I'm trying to run a simple batch script to uninstall a windows update.

```
@echo off
REM uninstall windows update 2592687
wusa /uninstall /kb:2592687 /norestart
```

When I run this from a command line it works fine, however when run from a C# Console App

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\kbunins.bat");
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        Process.Start(proc);
    }
```

I get a Installer encountered an error: 0x8000ffff Catastrophic failure error message
I've tried googling that error message and couldn't find anything useful and I tried to run cmd.exe with the bat file as an argument and I have tried running the command directly and I got the same results.

Edit: I've built the application and run the installer as an administrator but the update still isn't uninstalled. I've also added in the File.Exists() bit and it finds the file.

What would cause this?

Comment: Have you run the application with admin rights?

Comment: Also I'd verify that your application found the file using File.Exists before running.

Comment: I ran Visual Studio as an admin and it didn't work, will I have to build the application and run the installer as admin?

Answer (score 2):

Try to compile your app.

Go to bin folder. Right click on `EXE` file and choose *Run as Administrator*.

If this works, just assign Administrator permission from your code (if you can do so).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check to see if your file exists before running.
Something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\elloBatch.bat");
   if(File.Exists(path))
   {
      ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
      Process.Start(proc);
   }
   else
   {
      Console.Write("File not at specified location.");
   }
}
```

Also if possible I'd recommend you add your batch to your project (or drop it in the same location as your executable) and just reference it by file name.